# Adapter getView() methosd ResourcesNotFound Exception in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter, android-adapterview

In Fragment class set the custom dialog, in this dialog put the list view and set the value. But my adapter class `getView()` method is crashing. (`ResourcesNotFoundException`)

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(view==null) {
            viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            view = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.partner_citylistitem, null);
            viewHolder.firstName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.partnercityvalue);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.firstName.setText(datas.get(i).getCity());

        return view;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView firstName;
    }
```

Comment: problem is here datas.get(i).getCity()

Comment: check value of datas

Comment: datas.get(1).getCity() put this line logcat and checked values are print

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
     final   ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(view==null) {

            viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.partner_citylistitem, parent, false);
            viewHolder.firstName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.partnercityvalue);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
           }

        viewHolder.firstName.setText(datas.get(i).getCity());

        return view;
 }
```

and also check the **values of data**

Comment: view = vi.inflate(R.layout.partner_citylistitem, parent, false); in this line cannot resolve  sysmbol parent error showing, Here what i have to give

Comment: i give null instead of parent. Process: com.partner.android, PID: 2969 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04003b
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
 atandroid.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2312)
 atandroid.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)         atcom.superantzpartner.android.Adapters.CityListAdapter.getView(CityListAdapter.java:55)  atandroid.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)

Comment: same adapter i am using in two modules, In my first modules it works fine, but in second module its crashing

Comment: Sorry, insted parents use viewGroup which is the parameter of the getView() method

Comment: all things are going right means programming. Now you have to sure check the values of datas i.e. datas.get(i).getCity()

Comment: datas.get(i).getCity() here values are coming and put the logcat and checked.